# How to activate sqlite WAL with PHP?

Tags: php, sqlite, wal

I write this:

```
$db = new PDO("sqlite:$dbname");
$db->exec("PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;");
#.....                        
$wal_status = $db->exec("PRAGMA journal_mode;");
echo "WAL-status: ".$wal_status;
```

The www-page says: "WAL-status: 0"
---I think this means: WAL is not activated.

What must I do?
Thx in advance for your hints.

Comment: Perhaps it is an in-memory database? See the last paragraph here: https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode

Comment: I don't think so.
In a config.php I specified a disk file xxxsqlite.db.
This db is called by my code shown above ($dbname),
and it is stored on the disk of my webspace provider.

Comment: You're using [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) which returns the number of affected rows. Zero is the correct number. Maybe [query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) will work as you expect? I have not tested this...

Answer (score -2):

I asked chatGPT, and it answered:

Do not use
`$wal_status = $db->exec("PRAGMA journal_mode;");`
but use
`$wal_status = $db->query("PRAGMA journal_mode;")->fetchColumn();`

chatGPT also said the reason, I don't write it here.
It's proposal works good, problem is solved.

Comment: Next time, don't use chatGPT, but read the documentation. You can solve more problems quicker that way. It might even help you to prevent making similar mistakes in the future.